# Excerpt length and alignment

Tags: excerpt

I want excerpt to be appear in paragraph, atleast 400 words and  words should not be cut at end. [This](http://www.hechopor51.com/) is my website and it should be align left.

i want excerpt like single post style. And i dont want to have "....".

Answer (score 0):

```
add_filter( 'excerpt_length', function($length) { return 400; }, 999 );
add_filter('excerpt_more', function($more) { return ''; });
```

*another edit:* this **will** cut words at the end, not in the middle of some word. I'm sorry if I understood the request wrong. And be free to change 400 to any amount of words you want to show.

add that to your functions.php

**edit:** You say you wan't it to "appear in paragraph". I'm not sure what you mean by that, can't you just put `<p>...</p>` around it?

And alignment? That's what your CSS is for, be more specific, please.

Comment: i want excerpt to align as single post type. and dont want .... at the end.

Comment: I added the code to remove the "..."